# Append text to filename in PHP?

Tags: php

Hello:  I am relatively new to PHP.   I have a directory with 16 .jpg files in it. (eg:  /images/boxer1.jpg, boxer2.jpg etc...)

As part of a larger PHP file copy and upload procedure, I want to create a second version of these files by appending a _h to the file (eg: boxer1_h.jpg, boxer2_h.jpg, etc..); leaving the new files in the same directory with the original files for further manipulation.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this using PHP programming?

Comment: You should not ask such type of questions here. No one is going to write the whole code for you.

Comment: You just copy the files and specify any name/path as destiny you like for each copy operation. That is pretty obvious. So what is your _real_ question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mureinik's answer is a good solution, it copies the uploaded file and changes it's name. Here is a good way to do it during the upload.

You used

```
move_uploaded_file ($uploaded, 'path/to/uploads/'.$filename);
```

Use it again:

```
move_uploaded_file ($uploaded, 'path/to/uploads/'.$str_replace('.', '_h.', $filename));
```

AND THAT, assuming you give a proper filename to the uploaded files without any other DOTS besides the one to separate the extension from the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of files in a directory using [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). Then, just replace the `.` with `_h.` and you're set to go:

```
$origFiles = scandir('/path/to/directory');
foreach ($origFiles as $origFile) {
    $destFile = $str_replace('.', '_h.', $origFile);
    copy($origFile, $destFile);
}
```

Comment: A few tweeks and it works like a charm:     $origFiles = scandir('images/testing');
array_splice($origFiles, 0, 2);
#echo "<pre>";
#print_r($origFiles);
#exit();

foreach ($origFiles as $origFile) {
    $destFile = str_replace('.', '_h.', $origFile);
    copy("images/testing/$origFile", "images/upload/$destFile");
}   I used array_splice to get rid of the "." ".." from the array.